# Javascript works fine with a hard-coded string but not with variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem I have bee struggling over all morning so I felt it was time to get some help! I have a javascript function which gets the value entered by a user into an autocomplete box, uses AJAX to send that value to a php script which queries the database and then populates the following box with the possible options. The problem is this all works fine when I hard-code in the selected option as so:

```
var selected="Ed Clancy";
```

but not when it pulls it from the box, as so:

```
var selected = this.getValue();
```

I have tried debugging this using an alert box and both boxes come up with the same string in them so I am completely puzzled! Any ideas? Full code below:

```
$(riderSelected).on('selectionchange', function(event){
    var selected = this.getValue();
    //var selected="Ed Clancy";
    alert(selected);
    $('#nap4').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#nap4').empty();
    $('#nap4').append($("<option>-select-</option>"));

    $.ajax({ 
type: "GET",
url: 'getbiketype.php',
data: { name: selected },
success:  function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  $('#nap4').append(data);
}
});

});
```

Comment: try alert(typeof selected); and see what you are getting for both the cases

Comment: There is no selectionchange. You have to use .on('change','..)

Also there is no this.getValue(); Its this.value;

Then your jquery selector is wrong (if your element isnt stored in a variable)

Can you provide us your full html/javascript code?

Comment: I get object for the variable but string for the hard-coded case  - sounds like the issue! How can I convert?

Comment: according to the documentation for _magicsuggest_  `getValue` returns an ARRAY, alert of an array with one string element will look identical to a string ... but it isn't - this is one reason why alert is the crappiest debugging tool, and why console.log and family are a better way to debug javascript (it's what console is made for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on *magicsuggest* documentation - http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html , you probably could do this

```
var selected = this.getValue()[0];
```

IF you do not allow multiple selection

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as I have written below for you .

**Code**

```
$(riderSelected).on('change', function (event) {
    var selected = this.value;
    alert(selected);
    $('#nap4').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#nap4').empty();
    $('#nap4').append($("<option>-select-</option>"));

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'getbiketype.php',
        data: {name: selected},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#nap4').append(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I am using getValue() as I am using a javascript plugin called magicsuggest to do the autocomplete so need to use that function to get the selected value returned. My thought is that maybe the getValue() function is still going when the AJAX is called so the 'selected' variable is empty?